# Python if/elif conditional

Tags: python

Is there a way to execute code in an if/elif structure so it evaluates all the code up to the elif? Here is an example:

```
i = 1 # this can be anything depending on what to user chooses

x = 5
y = 10

if i == 1:
    z = x + y

elif i == 2:
    # Here I want to return what would have happened if i == 1, in addition other stuff:
    r = x^3 - y

elif i == 3:
    # Again, execute all the stuff that would have happened if i == 1 or == 2, an addition to something new:
    # execute code for i == 1 and i == 2 as well as:
    s = i^3 + y^2
```

What I'm attemping to do is to avoid explicitly rewriting `z = x + y` in `elif == 2` etc.. because for my application there are hundreds of lines of code to be executed (unlike this trivial example). I guess I could wrap these things in function and call them, but I'm wondering if there is a more concise, pythonic way of doing it.

EDIT: The responses here seem to be focusing on the if/elif part of the code. I think this is my fault as I must not be explaining it clearly. If i == 2, I want to execute all the code for i == 2, in addition to executing the code for i == 1. I understand that I can just put the stuff under i == 1 into the i == 2 conditional, but since it's already there, is there a way to call it without rewriting it?

Comment: replace `elif` with `if`?

Comment: do you want to set `z` like you did in the `if i == 1`, if so make the `elif` an `if`?

Comment: @ReutSharabani I deleted my first post but upon thinking it over I'm pretty sure it's not. If `i == 2` then the `i == 1` block won't get hit.. still not what the OP wants

Comment: You are getting some crazy suggestions. Replacing `elif` with `if` will not help if the conditions are mutually exclusive. It looks like you would be better served by defining your actual conditions, which is to say not if `i < 2` followed by `i < 3` followed by `i < 4`. In other words, it looks like you progressively add more detail as `i` gets larger. Does this hold?

Comment: replace all the `==` with `>=`. i.e. use `if i >= 1` etc for everything.

Comment: If you always want `z = x + y` to execute, why have it inside an `if-statement` at all? Maybe I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: That first test `if i == 1` is obsolete (unless `i < 1` can happen?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
i = 1 # this can be anything depending on what to user chooses

x = 5
y = 10

if i >= 1:
    z = x + y

if i >= 2:
    # Here I want to return what would have happened if i == 1, in addition other stuff:
    r = x^3 - y

if i == 3:
    # Again, execute all the stuff that would have happened if i == 1 or == 2, an addition to something new:
    # execute code for i == 1 and i == 2 as well as:
    s = i^3 + y^2
```

Comment: Because no one ever said it was OK to modify `i`. In particular, it is used under `i==3` so you have changed the resulting answer. **You broke the OP's code.**

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Sorry. How about this version

Comment: It's not necessarily easy to know what OP really wanted, but I feel this answer in its present form either gets him there or gets him close.

Comment: This is the direction I wanted to head in. It's difficult to replicate my problem with a trivial example such as this one so I apologize if the question was not clear. But yes, this is very helpful.

Comment: @WillVousden Earlier, I had written an answer which changed the value of `i` by doing `i += 1` leading to it being downvoted. Later when I improved my answer, it was approved by people.

Answer (score 1):

How an if works is it will execute if the condition passes. Else if is only executed if none of the prior if/elif statements conditions pass. So you want all if statements not elif statements

```
 i = 1 # this can be anything depending on what to user chooses

x = 5
y = 10

if i >= 1:
    z = x + y

if i >=2:
    # Here I want to return what would have happened if i == 1, in addition other stuff:
    r = x^3 - y

if i >= 3:
    # Again, execute all the stuff that would have happened if i == 1 or == 2, an addition to something new:
    # execute code for i == 1 and i == 2 as well as:
    s = i^3 + y^2
```

Comment: the OP said they wanted `z = x + y` to also happen in the `i==2` case.

Comment: you should also change the first block to `i >= 1`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
if i in (1, 2, 3):
    z = x + y
if i in (2, 3):
    r = x^3 - y
if i == 3:
    s = i^3 + y^2
```

You can replace the tuples with `range(...)` when you have many cases.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding the question?  Why is this answer wrong?

Comment: I upvoted you because your answer works. The one I marked correct is more succinct and handles an indefinite amount of cases

Comment: @mk8efz Quite right! I was actually referring to the two downvotes on this answer (and the accepted answer also has two downvotes).